# Running a two-sample t.test with unequal sample size in R

Tags: r, t-test

I am trying to run a two-sample t-test for a difference between a treatment and control group. Data is not paired. When I subset my original dataframe, I found that I have unequal sample sizes (not an issue by hand, but R seems to make it an issue). Here is my code:

```
CG<-subset(data,treat=="Control")
TG<-subset(data,treat!="Control")
agep <-t.test(CG$age~TG$age)$p.value
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = CG$age ~ TG$age) : 
variable lengths differ (found for 'TG$age')
```

Yes! The lengths do differ. Not sure why that's a problem if I'm not running a paired test? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You're using the formula interface incorrectly. Try a comma instead of ~

Comment: Thank you! That was it! I can't believe I've been staring at this for hours over a comma. I appreciate it!

Comment: If you only have the two groups you could use the formula interface but you wouldn't want to subset your data first. t.test(age~treat, data=data) should do the same thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the unequal sample sizes are *independent groups*, then the mean can be parsed in R via an unpaired two-sample t-test.

First, ensure that your data pass a test of **homoscedasticity**--are the variances homogenous? We do this in R with a **Fisher's F-test**, `var.test(x, y)`.

```
CG <- subset(data, treat == "Control")
TG <- subset(data, treat != "Control")
var.test(CG, TG)
```

If your *p* > 0.05, then you can assume that the variances of both samples are homogenous. In this case, we run a classic Student's two-sample t-test by setting the parameter `var.equal = TRUE`.

```
agep <- t.test(CG$age, TG$age, var.equal = TRUE)
```

If the F-test returns a *p* < 0.05, then you can assume that the variances of the two groups are different (**heteroscedasticity**). In this case, you can run a Welch t-statistic. Simply set `var.equal = FALSE`.

```
agep <- t.test(CG$age, TG$age, var.equal = FALSE)
```